# pandas regex to extract network IP address substring

Tags: python, regex, pandas, ip-address

How can I find a ip network using regex?

Example

```
IP 
234.523.213.462:321
21.236.432.123:66666
213.406.421.436:7324
```

I wanna

```
IP                Port 
234.523.213.462   321
21.236.432.123    66666
213.406.421.436   7324
```

Need Help!
Thanks.

Comment: By the way, port number cannot be `66666`, port number is an integer in range 1-65535.

Answer (score 5):

Use vectorize pandas method [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html):

```
df[['IP','Port']] = df.IP.str.split(':', expand=True)
print (df)
                IP   Port
0  234.523.213.462    321
1   21.236.432.123  66666
2  213.406.421.436   7324
```

Solution with regex (if there are only numbers, `:` and `.`):

```
df[['IP','Port']] = df.IP.str.extract('(.*):(.*)', expand=True)
print (df)
                IP   Port
0  234.523.213.462    321
1   21.236.432.123  66666
2  213.406.421.436   7324
```

Answer (score 2):

Regex is overcomplication for this task.

```
In [1]: "213.406.421.436:7324".split(":")
Out[1]: ['213.406.421.436', '7324']

In [2]: "213.406.421.436:7324".split(":")[0]
Out[2]: '213.406.421.436'

In [3]: "213.406.421.436:7324".split(":")[1]
Out[3]: '7324'
```

You can get both ip and port from your string like this:

```
ip, port = "213.406.421.436:7324".split(":")
```

Answer (score 2):

using `pd.Series.str.extract`

***simple `regex`***

```
df.IP.str.extract('(?P<IP>.+):(?P<Port>\d+)', expand=True)

            IP   Port
0  523.213.462    321
1  236.432.123  66666
2  406.421.436   7324
```

***explicit `regex`***

```
df.IP.str.extract('(?P<IP>\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}):(?P<Port>\d+)', expand=True)

            IP   Port
0  523.213.462    321
1  236.432.123  66666
2  406.421.436   7324
```